# Can a webservice not support JSONP?

Tags: javascript, jsonp

I am trying to get data using [WorldBank API](http://data.worldbank.org/querybuilder). The webservice call that I am making is [this](http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/3.1_LOW.SEC.NEW.TEACHERS?per_page=50&date=1960:2013&format=json). This code doesnt work.

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/3.1_LOW.SEC.NEW.TEACHERS?per_page=50&date=1960:2013&format=json',
  jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(e) {
     console.log(e.message);
  }
});
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What isn't working? Is the call successful but the returned data is incorrect?

Comment: *"This code doesnt work."* Any time you find yourself writing "...doesn't work." in a technical question, backspace over it and say **exactly** what's happening, **exactly** what you expect to happen instead, and **why** you think that's what should be happening.

Comment: Thanks for the tip T.J. I will be more clear next time! @Krister: Got the answer for issue, thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JSON` and `JSONP` are entirely different things. You're asking it for JSON, but telling jQuery you're asking for JSONP. So that's not going to work.

It does [support JSONP](http://data.worldbank.org/node/11) if you tell it to. You should use `format=jsonP` and `prefix=the_name_of_your_callback`. Since you want jQuery to control the callback name, you will want the `jsonp` argument to tell it that the API uses the non-standard `prefix` argument (rather than `callback`, which is the standard one).

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'http://api.worldbank.org/countries/indicators/3.1_LOW.SEC.NEW.TEACHERS?per_page=50&date=1960:2013&format=jsonP',
  jsonp: 'prefix',
  dataType: 'jsonp',
  success: function(data) {
     console.log(data);
  },
  error: function(e) {
     console.log(e.message);
  }
});
```

[Working Example](http://jsbin.com/ovujib/1) | [Source](http://jsbin.com/ovujib/1/edit)

Notes on the above:

- Removed `type: "GET"`. JSONP is **always** `GET`.
- Changed `format=json` to `format=jsonP` in the URL.
- Removed `jsonpCallback: 'jsonpCallback'`. That argument tells jQuery to use a specific name for the callback function, which we don't want.
- Added `jsonp: 'prefix'`, which tells jQuery what argument to use in the query string for the name of the callback function. That API documents it uses `prefix` instead of the more standard `callback`.
- Removed `contentType: "application/json"`. You're not **sending** JSON, you're expecting to *receive* JSON.

Answer (score 0):

> Can a webservice not support JSONP?

Yes. A web service can support (or not support) whatever data formats it likes.

The URL you are requesting is returning JSON, not JSONP.